# Using powershell to connect to azure ad using access token

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm writing a powershell script to connect to azure ad using access token. I'm using below command:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "$tenantId"  -AadAccessToken $tokenResponse.access_token -AccountId "$appId"
```

I have given application "Contirbute" & "Global Administrator" Role, also Application has all required permissions.

When I execute the script I can connect to Azure AD but if I try to run subsequent commands after this it gives be below error.
 
Please assist me on this further.

```
Get-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing GetUsers
Code: Authentication_ExpiredToken
Message: Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request.
HttpStatusCode: Unauthorized
HttpStatusDescription: Unauthorized
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At C:\Users\kajalchaudhari\Desktop\test_connect.ps1:22 char:1
+ Get-AzureADUser -Top 10
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADUser], ApiException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetUser
```

Answer (score 4):

The error means the AAD Graph token you passed has expired, you need to pass a new one.

Or if you want to automate this, you could follow the steps below.

1.First, make sure you have installed the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-3.8.0) module. Then get the [`application id`, `tenant id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in), [`client secret`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret) of the AD App which is the global admin.

2.Then run the script below, it works fine on my side.

```
$azureAplicationId ="<application id>"
$azureTenantId= "<tenant id>"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<client secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal

$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id

Get-AzureADUser
```

[image]

Comment: The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.HResult. I am trying to now login with service principal but it says connect-azureid is not recognized

Comment: Check to make sure that the AzureAD module is installed and that the execution policy is proper.

Comment: Tried to follow this answer step by step but still can not get Get-AzureADUser work.
Get-AzureADUser shows "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." 
Get-AzADUser works fine under same login context.


Any idea why Get-AzureADUser get "Insufficient privileges" error ?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need to configure the token expiry in Azure AD.
if you have already done that and the error message is instant then see if following blog is helpful

https://www.insight.com/en_US/content-and-resources/tech-tutorials/azure-active-directory-authentication-token.html